# What is the origin of Jataka tales?

Tags: ancient-history, india, cultural-history, buddhism

Some of the [Jataka Tales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jataka_tales) are supposed to be about the Buddha in prior lives so the entire collection is touted as Buddhist by many.  However, other sources will say they are tales handed down through oral tradition that begins before recorded history.  My guess is many of the tales were already favorite tales that Buddha added two cents too, and a few were new, but that is only a guess.  Is there any good evidence about the origins of some or all of these tales?

Answer (score 3):

[The Jataka Tales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jataka_tales) are moral tales, probably written down in this form in the 4th century, ie probably a 50 to 150 years after the life of Gautama Buddha.

Yes, many of these stories predate Buddha. Some of the stories are variants of stories believed to have been told by [Aesop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesop%27s_Fables) in the 7th century BC, for example.

I don't think Gautama Buddha added anything to these stories. The claim that they are about his earlier lives is probably something that arrives only well after his death.

Comment: How interesting - a connection with Aesop?  from so far away!  Goes to show how complex and linked they really were through trade - even then.  Just that there is a possibility.

Comment: @balancedmama 
 
There's loads of connections between ancient Greece and India. And at this time Greece was the western and India the eastern neighbor of the Achaemenid empire. The whole of Afro-Eurasia is interconnected.

Comment: Is there a good source for approximate dates of origination for separate tales?

Comment: @balancedmama I know there has been a lot of analysis on the Aesop fables, but I don't know if there has been anything done like that on the Jataka tales.

Comment: @LennartRegebro You have claimed in your second paragraph that some of the Jataka Tales have been told by Aesop. Please provide proof.

Comment: @Samprity http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ass_in_the_Lion%27s_Skin http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cock,_the_Dog_and_the_Fox http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fox_and_the_Crow_%28Aesop%29 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lion,_the_Bear_and_the_Fox http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolf_and_the_Crane http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ass_and_the_Pig http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Goose_That_Laid_the_Golden_Eggs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tortoise_and_the_Birds

Comment: @LennartRegebro Thank you. I like stories.